# MySQL Filter One Table By Another

Tags: mysql, join, filtering

I know this is possible I just dont know how to the code or how to phrase it to search for the answer I need. I am pretty sure I need to use JOIN but again I am finding it hard to find an example to get the correct syntax.

I have 3 tables. An events table, which contains events that occur on different machines and their times. So for questions purposes events had 4 fields:

EVENTS

event_id (primary key, auto_increment)

machine_id (foreign key)

time_in

time_out

I then have a table "machines" which lists all of the machines:

MACHINES

id (key)

name

department_id (foreign key)

then lastly i have the Department table:

DEPARTMENTS

id (key)

name

I want to select all events that occur in a department. So say i want all events from events where the department_id of the machine the event occured on is = 1.

Comment: Which "event occurred on" are you referring to? Is not in the list of fields of any of your tables

Comment: if you could get me a list of event_id's that occured on a machine that would be perfect. There is a lot of other math going on is unrelated the the filter. The bigger picture is i am reporting the amount of time report in each department. The departments are defined by the machines in them. So the events table is written to with a machine_id with a timestamp. I find the timediff of the timestamps on a machine and i can get total time. What i am trying to do get just the time reported for a single department with id=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT E.event_id, E.machine_id, E.time_in, E.time_out
FROM EVENTS E
INNER JOIN MACHINES M ON E.machine_id=M.machine_id
WHERE M.department_id = 1
```

By the way, if you don't know the department id but know the name of the department, you can do an additional JOIN and use the department name:

```
SELECT E.event_id, E.machine_id, E.time_in, E.time_out
FROM EVENTS E
INNER JOIN MACHINES M ON E.machine_id=M.machine_id
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON M.department_id=D.department_id
WHERE D.Name = 'Accounting'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this

```
SELECT event_id, events.machine_id, time_in, time_out
FROM events 
     INNER JOIN machines ON events.machine_id = machine.id
     INNER JOIN departments ON machines.departments_id = departments.id
WHERE departments.id = 1
```

Note that I don't need to join to departments but for performance reason you should, this way you are always searching against a primary key, which has a clustered index and therefore a lot faster

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT e.* FROM events AS e, machines as m 
WHERE e.machine_id = m.id AND department_id = x;
```

or if you have the department name

```
SELECT e.* FROM events AS e, machines as m, departments as d 
WHERE e.machine_id = m.id AND m.department_d = d.id AND d.name = x;
```

This is a Cartesian product method. You can also use inner joins (other answers). Inner Joins are more readable and better ANSI syntax. [For more info about inner joins vs Cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1018825/493085)

Answer (score 0):

Use a join.

`SELECT events.* FROM events INNER JOIN machines ON machines.id = events.machine_id WHERE department_id = 1`